# Prove/Refute the following claim about convolution

Tags: laplace-transform, convolution

**Request**

I need to prove or to refute the the claim below, I tried to prove the claim but run into troubles with the $\Rightarrow$ side of the proof.

**Given**

$f$ is a continuous function $[0,\infty) \to \mathbb R $, then $ \forall t\geq0: (f * f)_t  = 0 $ iff $f\equiv0$.

**My solution**

The $\Leftarrow$ part of the proof is trivial, but how to prove the other direction? Maybe even my line of thought is wrong and i could refute the claim?

Note: We didn't prove that the transform is unique hence i cannot just use inverse Laplace transform and infer that $f(t)=0$.

Comment: Using the Laplace transform you would get $F(s)^2=0$ which implies $F(s)=0$ and that in turn $f(t)=0$. I'm not sure if there is a more primitive way. The difficulty is the inversion part of the Laplace transform, if you can not cite that as given.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Yes, to do that you need to prove a result about uniqueness for the Laplace transform. That's not the only problem: in fact the Laplace transform of a function as above need not exist. (Consider $e^{t^2}$ for example...)

Comment: Given that we didn't prove the Laplace transform is unique and exists, than how can i solve this?